# Store object in the session

Tags: grails

I would like to store some object in the session. I know, that there are at least two ways to do it:

- in the service define `scope = "session"`, and then define property `def myObject`
- use httpSession: `session['myObject'] = myObject`

<s>What is more useful approach to store object in the session?</s>

**Update:** What the benefites of using of every method? Can I invalidate session if I would use `scope = 'session'`?

**Update 2** If I would like to use object of another class in the service with `session = "session"`, I have an exception about bean with scope session.

Comment: Define 'useful approach' they are both useful in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided storing an object in the `session` itself would be the simpler approach. Just be sure whatever you do store there is as small as possible.

```
session['someKey'] = new MyObject()
```

The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html) has some more information about using the session.

Unless you have a requirement for using an actual instance of an object you may find it easier to simply store a map in the session instead.

```
session['someKey'] = [mapKey1: 'value', meaningKey: 42]
...
println session['someKey'].meaningKey // 42
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I need to store some data in the session for many users (unique data for unique user). Also I would like to manipulate session from grails service, is it good way? What is the best way to handle user's http session from service?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by manipulate from a service, but you can always pass the session into a service method as a parameter from a controller. e.g. myService.someMethod(someArg, someOtherArg, session)

Comment: I mean getting of session instance inside service, something like
`WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().getSession()`

Comment: So long as the thread/request is being made to the service from a web request then that will get the current session for that request.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch your idea, could you explain it a bit, please?

Comment: So long as the method you are calling in your service is being called by the user through a controller (e.g. the thread executing the service method is from a GrailsWebRequest) then the WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().getSession() in the service method will return the session for the user.